# libgcrypt - how to get length of data stored in buffer returned by gcry_cipher_encrypt()

Tags: c, libgcrypt

I am writing a simple program to encrypt and decrypt a c-string using libgcrypt.

In one part of my program, `gcry_cipher_encrypt()` is called like this:

`gcry_cipher_encrypt(handle, cipher_text, cipher_text_buf_len, plain_text, block_len);`

`cipher_text_buf_len` is the allocated size of `cipher_text`, which in my program is equal to the length of `plain_text`. This has also been suggested by the reference manual here:
https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gcrypt/Working-with-cipher-handles.html.

**Question**: I cannot figure out how to get the length of the data stored in the `cipher_text` buffer.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Varad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it. The answer is that the `gcry_cipher_encrypt()` function does **not** need to give the caller the length of the ciphertext. This is because in stream ciphers and block ciphers, the ciphertext is *always* the same length as the plaintext. Hence, the caller function itself could compute the length of the data stored in the buffer returned by `gcry_cipher_encrypt`

Quoting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_size_(cryptography):

> In modern cryptography, symmetric key ciphers are generally divided
> into stream ciphers and block ciphers. Block ciphers operate on a
> fixed length string of bits. The length of this bit string is the
> block size. Both the input (plaintext) and output (ciphertext) are the
> same length; the output cannot be shorter than the input – this
> follows logically from the pigeonhole principle and the fact that the
> cipher must be reversible – and it is undesirable for the output to be
> longer than the input.

It should be noted however, that if you plan to store or transmit your encrypted data, then you will need to save/send the initialization vector(iv) and plaintext padding information along with it.